# Syntax using the return value from an overloaded -> operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I think I might be overthinking this but I wanted to know if someone could clarify why the following statement works in the given code

```
f->hello();
```

This is the code

```
struct bar
{
    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World";
    }
};

struct foo
{
    bar* f;
    foo() {
        f = new bar();
    }

    ~foo() {
        delete f;
    }

    bar* operator->() {
        return f;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f->hello(); //Works
}
```

Since the following code from above returns a pointer

```
bar* operator->() {
        return f;
    }
```

should'nt

```
f->hello(); actually be f->->hello();
```

why does f->hello() work and f->->hello() fails ?
The reason i am thinking that f->->hello() should work is because

```
f->ptrReturned->hello();
```

If we overload the -> operator are we required to return a ptr type ? Form what I have tried it seems returning an object type is not allowed

Comment: ->-> is not a correct syntax. f->hello() is handled by the compiler.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler fudges this and re-applies the `->` operator to the returned pointer so you don't have the awkward syntax problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct basically, but `->->` is not valid syntax. You can use the overloaded `operator->` like

```
f.operator->()->hello();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^          return the pointer
//            ^^^^^^^^^ call hello() on the returned pointer
```

`f->hello()` is treated as the same of `f.operator->()->hello()`; that makes the usage of class with overloaded `operator->` (e.g. [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers)) consistent with built-in pointers. The usage would be more natural, and could be used with raw pointers in more general context like templates.

And,

> If we overload the -> operator are we required to return a ptr type ?

There're some [restrictions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Restrictions):

> The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which operator -> is in turn overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, that's just how an overloaded `operator->` works. The part before the `->` (not including the operator itself) gets replaced with the return value of the overloaded operator. For example, [`std::unique_ptr::operator->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) returns a pointer, which then gets dereferenced by the `->`.